# epoch time converted to date is different in MySQL & PHP both on UTC

Tags: php, mysql, date, utc

PHP & MySQL are returning different dates from epoch time.

```
1426723200
PHP date(): 03/19/2015
MySQL date: 03/18/2015 (FROM_UNIXTIME)

1426809599
PHP date(): 03/19/2015
MySQL date: 03/19/2015 (FROM_UNIXTIME)
```

my.cnf I have default-time-zone = 'UTC'
phpinfo shows the time zone as UTC

I don't see any offsets, but it's obvious there are. I can't find where the problem is though. Any ideas?

Comment: As a temporary solution, I am just adding 14440 seconds to the time value which is the offset MySQL is using. I'd rather have PHP and MySQL in sync than manually adding time.

Answer (score 0):

The OS has a timezone setting; what is it?

php.ini has date.timezone; what is it?

my.cnf has system_time_zone and time_zone; what are they?

(Technically, this is not an "answer".  But I believe it will lead you to the answer without my having to get on your machine.)